# how can the make infer what kind of compiler it needs for the final target?

Tags: c++, makefile

I've got a simple makefile here. It's a minimum c++ project and I'd like the make to do the correct behavior with the implicit rules. 
with the following makefile, it will report error. Then I type "make -n", it seems the make uses the cc rather than the cxx.
But when I checked the GNU page it says the CXX is a implicit variable:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

So can I say for the final target. The implicit tool is always cc?

```
objects = test.o main.o
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-std=c++11

test: $(objects)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o test
```

Comment: The command used for linking is in the `LD` variable. You need to set that to the correct frontend program (i.e. `g++`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thnx for the info. I edited my title, I think it's bit misleading. what I mean was something else.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should try to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) instead, I find it way more elegant and simple to use.

Comment: The problem is that `make` *doesn't* infer anything. It just uses the variable `LD` without checking where the object files come from. It really *can't* check where the object files come from, since the object files could come from many different sources and different languages (you could easily have Fortran, C and C++ in a single project, linking object files from all three languages into a single program).

Comment: Do you expect everyone to guess what the "error" is, or would you actually like to show the error message?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I described in the thread...CC is used as compiler, in this case, CC will not able to compile cpp files. This is also my question. Make command cannot infer from the final target what kind of compiler it needs?

Comment: I am unable to find any actual description of the actual error message. You know, the actual error message, verbatim. Like "file not found", or whatever. It's like calling an auto mechanic, telling him that "my car doesn't move", and expect the mechanic to know exactly what the problem is. Make "infers" based on its implicit rules, and there's nothing in the question that indicates which exact implicit rule it's trying to use. The execution of `cc` instead of `c++` can be as a result of either the wrong implicit rule, or the variables used by the right implicit rule not set correctly.

Comment: ... and without seeing the actual error message, it is not possible to determine which is the case.

Comment: @J.R., please [edit] the question to show the actual output.  Without that, it's impossible to say exactly what's needed (but I'm guessing that `LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)` is likely to help).

Comment: What are your source files named? Also, CFLAGS are for the C compiler, use CXXFLAGS for C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your object files are being linked with Make's default linker, which is `$(CC)`.  We can see that, if we look in the output of `make --print-data-base -f /dev/null` - in particular:

> ```make
> %: %.o
> #  recipe to execute (built-in):
>         $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
> ```

If we look at the definition of `LINK.o`, we see:

> ```make
> # default
> LINK.o = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
> ```

Luckily for us, Make provides `LINK.cc` for exactly our purpose:

> ```make
> # default
> LINK.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
> ```

So all we need to do is redefine `LINK.o` to be the the value of `LINK.cc`, and the linking will be done by our C++ compiler:

```make
LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)
```

If we had several targets, to be linked differently, we might use a target-dependent variable to localise the effect:

```make
test: LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)
```

---

Other comments on the makefile:

- `test` is a poor name for the program - it's easy to run the standard `/usr/bin/test` by mistake.
- You probably meant `CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11` (not `CFLAGS`).
- All makefiles should contain a `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` target, so that interrupted commands don't leave partial output that appears up-to-date.

Comment: Thnx for the explanation. So I thought the make can also determine which linker it needs for the correct behavior, e.g. c++ or c. So it seems make uses cc for all the .o file to link them?   So this step I cannot use the implicit variable except for c project.

Comment: Make uses the filenames to determine (e.g.) that `%.cpp` → `%.o` requires the C++ compiler.  Similarly for your C++ source direct to executable, if you have only one source file.  But once you have object files, it has just one rule for linking them - that's likely right for C, Fortran or Pascal, and it *can* be right for C++ (but only if you understand that linking with `g++` adds (at least) the Standard C++ library, and you manually add the necessary flags yourself to `LDLIBS`).  It's easier to set `LINK.o`, IMO.